unable to use msg type can_msgs/msg/Frame on ROS2 Humble with ros2 socketcan
I want to use the ros2_socketcan package in order to use CAN communication.
I use a PEAK CAN and i'm able to communicate using cansend / candump / cangen...
Few days ago i was able to use this command :
ros2 topic pub /to_can_bus can_msgs/msg/Frame "{header: {stamp: {sec: 0, nanosec: 0}, frame_id: 'can'}, is_rtr: false, is_extended: false, is_error: false, dlc: 8, data: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}"


in order to use the can_sender node of ros2_socketcan and i was able to see data on candump.
Now, when i try to use this command i have this error :
The passed message type is invalid


I tried to uninstall and install back ros2_socketcan -> no change.
I have sourced ros2/humble and my packages
I tried to uninstall and install back ros-humble-can-msgs -> no change.
I have files for the msg in ./opt/ros/humble/include/can_msgs
the auto completion for can_msg/msg/Frame don't work
ros2_socketcan node launched by socket_can_receiver.launch.py and socket_can_sender.launch.py can't pub or read from /to_can_bus and /from_can_bus topics. error ->  The message type 'can_msgs/msg/Frame' is invalid

update : when i use this command : sudo find -iname can_msgs, i don't see can_msgs into folders like /install or /build. Did the package under /opt/ros/humble isn't build ?
in conclusion, i don't understand why ros suddently isn't able to find can_msgs/msg/Frame in my packages..
thank you per advance for you're time and you're help !!
